# GDB doesnt like my typedef

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, typedef

It seems that the following is to deep for the debugger in Qt even though the program uses it without problem

```
typedef QMap <int, QStringList> day2FileNameType;
typedef QMap <int, day2FileNameType> month2day2FileNameType;
typedef QMap <int, month2day2FileNameType> year2month2day2FileNameType;

year2month2day2FileNameType y2m2d2f;
```

now the first 2 typeDefs work okay with the debugger but the third one
retrieving data for watch view (over 100 pending request)

Is it wrong for me to try and use such a typedef as year2month2day2FileNameType?

Comment: It seems like there's more to this question.  Did you run into an error when running the application?  Maybe you have invalid data somewhere.

Comment: I havent noticed any errors, I havent checked for any leaks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't even use QT (although I do use gdb), but if you google 'gdb typdef', you get A LOT of hits like this one:

http://qtcreator.blogspot.com/2009/07/gdb-typedef-bug-update.html

So if what you say is true, that the program, unchanged, runs when you use the same structure minus the typdefs, I would assume that this is, in fact, a bug. Maybe this one (or something similar) applies to your code:

http://osdir.com/ml/gdb.bugs.discuss/2004-09/msg00035.html

Comment: thanks for the link, what I meant is that the program itself runs fine but when I want to inspect a value inside this data type the GDB crashes.  But you gave me an idea, I probably could have better succes without the typedef, gonna try it.